# How to copy objects from the default local realm to a MongoDB synced realm using Swift?

Tags: ios, swift, realm, mongodb-realm

The alternative title is "How to deep copies data from an offline realm to a synced realm using Swift?"

After found out that the only option for [How to upgrade a local realm to a synced realm?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/68797154/how-to-upgrade-a-local-realm-to-a-synced-realm) is to "clone" or copy all data from the local default realm to the synced realm, then the next question is how to perform the data cloning or copying for a local realm with complicated relationships between data objects.

Is there a recommended approach to copy the data from one realm to a synced realm while keeping the relationship between objects?

There was a `realm.copyFromRealm` method but seems already deprecated.

**Update**

Found an official guide on "Add Sync to a Local-Only App", https://docs.mongodb.com/realm/sync/local-to-sync/

Comment: This is a very good question - but it's essentially a duplicate of your prior question so it would be best to keep all of the data points in one place so future readers will have an easier time locating the answers and other data you're providing. It's a complex question too because there are a lot of if's, and's and but's involved.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**Update**

Found a potential workaround for this issue in "How can I easily duplicate/copy an existing realm object" using `Codable` with `JSONEncoder` and `JSONDecoder`, https://stackoverflow.com/a/65436546/2226315

Found another function in [GitHub Gist](https://gist.github.com/LikeCarter/b9f9da8ce6c0c1feadddeedfab474f38) migrates local realm to a synced realm, however, the code seems already outdated.

---

Found a GitHub issue raised in 2014 about how to move/copy objects between realms, https://github.com/realm/realm-cocoa/issues/1076. `createInRealm:withObject:` was suggested in the comment.

However, after digging into the source code only `createInRealm:withValue:` is available in Objective-C API, https://github.com/realm/realm-cocoa/blob/84179b4e0b54e11f73723c283c4567c565da62f5/Realm/RLMObject.h#L174

In the official guide on "Add Sync to a Local-Only App", there is a section about ["Copy Existing Data"](https://docs.mongodb.com/realm/sync/local-to-sync/#copy-existing-data) which outlines the flow to copy data from a local realm to a synced realm.

[image]

**Relevant Info**

- [Converting local realms to synced realm](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/49958047/converting-local-realms-to-synced-realm)
- https://github.com/realm/realm-cocoa/issues/5381